# How to set initial connections of a dynamic data source

Tags: spring-boot, database-connection, datasource, multi-tenant, sharding

I have a multi-tenant application with multiple datasources. The exact url which its connecting is set by runtime, depending on a request parameter. When I make a request at default 10 database-connections are created. With multiple datasources this fast sums up to a lot of connections. So I want to lower that number and also close the connections after a certain time.

**My Configuration Class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.example.demo",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "multiEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "multiTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private final String PACKAGE_SCAN = "com.example.demo";

//datasources
@Primary
@Bean(name = "COMP1")
public DataSource company1DS() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .username("root")
            .password("password")
            .url("jdbc:mysql://81.123.456.789:3306/company1")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "COMP2")
public DataSource company2DS() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .username("root")
            .password("password")
            .url("jdbc:mysql://81.123.456.789:3306/company2")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "multiRoutingDataSource")
public DataSource multiRoutingDataSource() {
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
    targetDataSources.put("COMP1", company1DS());
    targetDataSources.put("COMP2", company2DS());
    MultiRoutingDataSource multiRoutingDataSource = new MultiRoutingDataSource();
    multiRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(company1DS());
    multiRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    return multiRoutingDataSource;
}
@Bean(name = "multiEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean multiEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return em;
}
@Bean(name = "multiTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager multiTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            multiEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
@Primary
@Bean(name = "dbSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean dbSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    return properties;
}
```

}

**What I already tried:**

I tried to change the values in the application.properties file like so:

```
spring.datasource.maxActive=2
spring.datasource.minIdle=2
spring.datasource.maxIdle=5
spring.datasource.initialSize=2
```

I tried to change the properties the dynamic way (PersistenceConfiguration.hibernateProperties()):

```
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("spring.datasource.maxActive",2);
        properties.put("spring.datasource.minIdle",2);
        properties.put("spring.datasource.maxIdle",5);
        properties.put("spring.datasource.initialSize",2);
        return properties;
    }
```

But it seems that no properties get applied. When I show `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Connections';` in the MySQL workbench, I always get 10 more connections after I made a request from a new datasource.

If there is any important information missing, please let me know and I will add it.

I really appreciate your effort,
Greetings Alexander

**EDIT**

Since spring.datasource.max-active=2 is not valid, I also tried all the following in application-properties, as well as in the `hibernateProperties();`

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=2
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=2

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put("spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size",2);
        properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size",2);
        properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle",2);
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size","2");
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size","2");
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle","2");
        return properties;
    }
```

Nothing changed a thing

Comment: What version of Spring Boot is this? There's no such `spring.datasource.max-active`  and the like properties. Please refer to the reference documentation for the list of supported properties or use your IDE if it has SB support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its Version 2.2.2 RELEASE. I have edited what I also tried (from docu: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html). However it also didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I misread the initial code. You are creating the `DataSource` yourself, none of that binding from `spring.datasource` will work. Please refer to the reference guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: Thank you so much, in all my confusion I somehow did not find that solution. Thanks, it works fine